# How does the putspecialobject opcode in the RubyVM work?

Tags: ruby, opcode, vm-implementation

I'm working on an implementation of the RubyVM and I've searched all over for some documentation on the opcodes, but to no avail.

If anyone knows specifically how the `putspecialobject` opcode works, or even just a link to some fullish documentation I'd much appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From insns.def:

```
DEFINE_INSN putspecialobject (rb_num_t value_type) () (VALUE val)
{
  switch (value_type) {
    case VM_SPECIAL_OBJECT_VMCORE:
      val = rb_mRubyVMFrozenCore;
      break;
    case VM_SPECIAL_OBJECT_CBASE:
      val = vm_get_cbase(GET_ISEQ(), GET_LFP(), GET_DFP());
      break;
    default:
      rb_bug("putspecialobject insn: unknown value_type");
  }
}
```

where:

```
VM_SPECIAL_OBJECT_VMCORE = 1
VM_SPECIAL_OBJECT_CBASE  = 2
```

In other words, if the argument is 1, `rb_mRubyVMFrozenCore` is pushed on the stack, which is an object created early in VM startup that implements some language features as methods:

```
set_method_alias(klass,:new,:old)             alias new old
set_variable_alias(:$new,:$old)               alias $new $old
undef_method(klass,:foo)                      undef foo
define_method(klass,:foo,&block)              def foo ... end
define_singleton_method(obj,:foo,&block)      def obj.foo ... end
set_postexe(&block)                           END { ... }
```

If the argument is 2, the class/module for the current *class context* is pushed on the stack. That's the lexical scope in which constants are resolved and `def` and `alias` take effect. It's also the class passed as 'klass' to the methods above.

So

```
def foo
  ...
end
```

compiles to this:

```
[:putspecialobject, 1],
[:putspecialobject, 2],
[:putobject, :foo],
[:putiseq, [...]],
[:send, :"core#define_method", 3, nil, 0, nil]
```

This is as much as I could reverse engineer, which isn't easy with this code.